# Грамотна ли фраза?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"На первом этаже гостиницы располагается пост службы охраны, кафе-бар, !!!гостевые лифты!!!, служба приёма и размещения гостей".

Answer (score 2):

*На первом этаже гостиницы располага**Ю**тся пост службы охраны, кафе-бар, служба приёма и размещения гостей. Здание оборудовано лифтами для гостей.*

Во-первых; если объектов несколько, то глагол "располагаться" нужно употребить во множественном числе.
Во-вторых; лифтами, как понимаю, оборудован не только первый этаж, а следовательно они расположены в здании целиком, а с первого этажа они периодически отъезжают.
Ну, и в-третьих; лично мне что такое гостевые лифты не очень понятно. Догадываюсь, что это антоним грузового лифта, или лифта для персонала, но выражение распространено довольно слабо и больше похоже на гостиничный сленг, который в тексте для неслужебного пользования (если текст для неслужебного) лучше избегать, хотя тут могу и ошибаться.

Comment: Спасибо)))

Answer (score 1):

Мне не нравится в Вашей фразе повторение слов "служба" и "гостевые/гостей". Думаю, что лучше написать так: "На первом этаже гостиницы располагаются пост охраны, кафе-бар,  лифты для гостей, служба приема и размещения постояльцев."